# JTable - Add, update, delete row , so far I only did Add

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I have an assignment to do, in which I have to add to a table. what i'm trying to do is enter details in JTextField and when i press the add button I want it to add to the JTable.
the code is as follows:

```
    addPatient = new JButton("ADD PATIENT");
    addPatient.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.BOLD, 10));
    addPatient.setBounds(10,230,110,30);
    add(addPatient);
    //Add action listener to button
    addPatient.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        private void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
           DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel) patientTable.getModel();
         if(!patientNameText.getText().trim().equals(""))
         {
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{patientNameText.getText(), patientDOBText.getText(),     patientAddressText.getText(), patientPhoneText.getText()});
                   }
                 else
            {
                patientNameText.setText("Should not be left blanl!");
            }
        }
    });
```

I'm not trying to do anything to complicated. and i'm using BlueJ.
when I press add nothing happens.

any help would be appreciated  Thanks

Comment: This probably means that you need to implement/override the abstract method `ActionEvent` or something along those lines. But since this probably is about homework, try and find out yourself. Don't let others do your homework for you.

Comment: I've been trying to figure it out for the past weeks a couple of hours a day. it's due tomorrow, my lecturer is not a great help, and i'm really stuck. I've been doing bit by bit every day, but the add,edit,and delete button are driving me crazy by now. and no one wants to help me.

Comment: Is the addRow() method executing? Did you add a System.out.println(...) statement to verify this?

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. You're creating an ActionListener, which requires an actionPerformed() method. You only have a bAddActionPerformed() method.

Comment: I changed it to actionPerformed and the same error message is still occuring

Comment: addPatient.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
 DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel) patientTable.getModel();
if(!patientNameText.getText().trim().equals(""))
{
model.addRow(new Object[]{patientNameText.getText(), patientDOBText.getText(), patientAddressText.getText(), patientPhoneText.getText()});
}
 else
{
patientNameText.setText("Should not be left blanl!");
}
}
});

Comment: Error message is gone now with the above code but it still doesn't add text from a Jtextfield to the table?

Comment: @KamilaMagdziak Then post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ask another question.